# Different artifacts for cloud and on-premise deployment

Tags: spring-boot

What are some best-practices for a Spring-Boot project, which creates two artifacts (one for cloud and one for on-premise deployment), where just some Spring Beans are implemented differently (e.g. for login, etc.) and the artifacts should not contain code from the other deployment? What are best-practices to unit test and integration test those instances without long build time due to executing tests multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test services without spring context (so you don't have to choose between different contexts in tests, also test times will be smaller) - these will be simple unit tests. 
Use spring test context for integrational tests with these specific Spring Beans.

Comment: So you would not place any integration tests in the "common" module? How to prevent a lot of duplicated (integration) tests within the specific modules. (e.g. a lot of requests have the same outcome independent of the cloud or the on-premise version)

Comment: Your controllers should be as thin as possible, preferably just a one-liner call to underlying Service class. Test Service classes with their dependencies, without Spring Context. In this case, no need to cover one-liners from controllers, as majority of logic is in Service class, and it is unit tested.

Answer (score 1):

You will be building libraries like in the below given model. All the features will be abstracted like microservices which can be developed, tested, the main framework will have integration tests to the external services and the core application will have it's own tests.

[image: Loosely Couple features with Unit Tests and Integration]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to create a config file with @Profile("cloud") annotation.

Please look the following links.

- [Spring Boot official Link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html)
- List item

[Example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Hoping this helps. As in this way you can configure all your environments.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. This article (https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-profiles/#dont-use-profiles-for-application-modes) advises against using Profiles for "application modes".

Comment: sorry I missed the last lines which actually asking for testing. And this is what we can use for production environment but not as a part of testing.